# Is there a way to sort a no. of character arrays in alphabetical order without using the #include<string.h> or #include<stdlib.h>?

Tags: c

So, I have tried to do the same in a case of array of structures where 'char name[100]' is the only data member.
[1st part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDlEk.png)

[2nd part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNAhK.png)

The problem that I have encountered here is that once I provide a no. of names during program runtime, the output screen either does not print anything afterwards, or, prints the data without sorting it.
[output screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKlYq.png)

I did not get any compile time errors so I believe that there is a flaw in the logic.

There's this another method I tried hoping to get positive results. I type-casted characters to integers hoping that ASCII values could be used to compare. But, the results are exactly the same (undesired results).
[updated logic of the 2nd part of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AohUb.png)

I hope somebody helps me find a way to correct this logic or provide another logic that is efficient.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please peruse our [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help). If you prepare a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the bug will probably reveal itself to you; if it does not, you can post the code in your question (not a link to the code, not a screenshot, but the actual text).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code but post code as properly formatted text. You probably should also read this: [ask]

Answer (score -1):

the sorting logic you used is good , but from what is see the use of function's in C need's to be provided by pointers. other wise all the data inside the function will born and die inside the function , and the all the variables in the Main will stay the same as given, that explains why the output is the same as the input
try to print inside the sorting function's to see if this is the problem.

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you, but i still received the undesirable output.
Although, this time, apart from printing the data without sorting it, the output screen stopped printing anything afterwards (as i mentioned earlier).
i did think about using pointers to pass into functions and the use of static variables to avoid dangling pointers, but this program is just a small portion of the project that i am working on. so, use of a lot of pointers and local variables was making the code more complicated for me to read. which is why, i started using global variables.